# Reach one item from an API

Tags: python, arrays, json, api

I am trying to reach this: 8710002b061e4959ac09c4db1c1b3021 from an API.

I have done this in python:

```
minecraftName = input("Minecraft Username: ")

f = requests.get(
    "https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=[not allowed to show]&name=" + minecraftName).json()
profile = []
profile.append(f["player"]["stats"]["SkyBlock"]["profiles"])

print(profile[:1])
```

but I get the output:

```
[{'8710002b061e4959ac09c4db1c1b3021': {'profile_id': '8710002b061e4959ac09c4db1c1b3021', 'cute_name': 'Pear'}}]
```

and I'm only interested in the first part, or the part by "profile_id". The API looks like this:

```
"SkyBlock": {
        "profiles": {
          "8710002b061e4959ac09c4db1c1b3021": {
            "profile_id": "8710002b061e4959ac09c4db1c1b3021",
            "cute_name": "Pear"
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
profile = []
profile.append(list(f["player"]["stats"]["SkyBlock"]["profiles"].keys())[0])
```